# Can I hide a column in tableView widget in Corona?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

Can I hide a column in a tableView in Corona?  Basically, I want to query a database and pull back two fields...I want to display one field in the table but I need to keep the other value attached to each row without displaying it.  If this isn't possible with tableView, is there an easy alternate way to accomplish this?  Thanks.

The code is below - I am doing a select from the database to get the TITLE and the ID for the newTableView.  I want to hide the ID.
Will look into isVisible per your suggestion.

```
local function onRowRender( event )  
    local row = event.row  
    local font = native.systemFont  
    local fontSize = 18  
    local rowHeight = row.height / 2        

    -- for display   
    local options_title = {  
        parent = row,  
        text = row.params.TITLE,  
        x = 50,  
        y = rowHeight,  
        font = font,  
        fontSize = fontSize,  
    }  

    --add row object
    row.title = display.newText( options_title )
    row.title.anchorX = 0
    row.title:setFillColor( 0 )  

    -----I'd like to hide this ID column!------
    local options_id = {
        parent = row,
        text = row.params.ID,
        x = 50,
        y = rowHeight,
        font = font,
        fontSize = fontSize,
    }
    -- add row object
    row.id = display.newText( options_id )
    row.id.anchorX = 0
    row.id:setFillColor( 1,0,0 )

end
```

Comment: Don't fetch the second field at all?

Comment: I wanted to have the second field available without having to hit the database again.

Comment: Please show the code that you currently have? I'd better understand it than the corona API.

Comment: can you make the second column text's DisplayObject invisible using the isVisible property?

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  I'm trying to post my code but haven't had luck with the mini-Markdown formatting yet.  Will work on that and also look at isVisible now.

Comment: Ok I added the code by editing original post.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, rpattiso, I just added this line
row.id.alpha = 0
just before row.id.anchorX = 0 
and it seems to be working.